# Store 3rd party library object in database

Tags: java, spring-boot, dmn

Dear Stackoverflow community,

I'm developing a spring boot application which is using 3rd party library (https://github.com/goldmansachs/jdmn)

There is an object called `TDefinitions` which holds information about .dmn diagram.
Somehow I need to persist this object or all the information that this object contains in my database, using Spring Data JPA repository. So that I can reuse it whenever I run my application again.

Could you please assist me what would be the ways to achieve that? Store it as a Blob or maybe serialize it somehow as a Json?
The problem is it's not a simple object. Here's part of it's definition:

```
    @JsonPropertyOrder({...})
public class TDefinitions extends TNamedElement implements Visitable {
    @JsonProperty("import")
    private List<TImport> _import;
    private List<TItemDefinition> itemDefinition;
    private List<TDRGElement> drgElement;
    private List<TArtifact> artifact;
    private List<TElementCollection> elementCollection;
    private List<TBusinessContextElement> businessContextElement;
    private DMNDI dmndi;
    private String expressionLanguage;
    private String typeLanguage;

[...]
```

How should I approach this problem from architectural perspective? How should I design my app? Provide interfaces/classes that extend elements from this library?

Comment: Create blob/clob field, and put it there. Question is why do you need it? That is something to be used to generate code... so I would keep it with source code, and generate java-code when needed.

Comment: Can't you create the .dmn out of that object and store that? Might be better than serializing the object that deals with it as I'd assume .dmn already is a format meant for storage and exchange.

Comment: @Michał Zaborowski I'm no sure what you mean

Comment: You can write anything to blob. Clob is large object, but text. If you can serialize it - it can be stored. According to their docs - this is just a notation - from that you create java code, and that is something you can use... If so - I would store that dmns with code - as documents / for future changes.

Comment: But then everyytime I want to evaluate decision from the DMN model I need to create this model from .dmn file and it takes time

Answer (score 0):

I'd prefer NoSQL such as MongoDB for storing these types of objects. If you have to use SQL for some reason, then go with JSON.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).